# Android: ActionBar (Android support library)

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

i have a problem with ActionBarCompat (from support library).
I have no idea how I can add a few buttons on ActionBar where I drew black circle (on screenshot) together with menu in the left of the screen.

Please, I need help!

[image]

Code of menu in ActionBar in the left of the screen.

```
     private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawer;
    private ActionBarHelper mActionBar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

...

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        linearLayout.setId(LAYOUT_ID);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DDrawerListener());
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

...
        fragments = new  Fragment[NUMBER_OF_TABS];
        mDrawer.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));
        mDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab));
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        mActionBar = createActionBarHelper();
        mActionBar.init();


        mDrawer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e5c391"));
        mDrawer.setCacheColorHint(Color.parseColor("#e5c391"));

        initArrays(this);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
        (this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.string.app_drawer_open, R.string.app_drawer_close);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            addFragment(0);
        }
```

Welcome other ways too =)
Thank you!
Happy New Year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html:

**Specify the Actions in XML**

All action buttons and other items available in the action overflow are defined in an XML menu resource. To add actions to the action bar, create a new XML file in your project's res/menu/ directory.

Add an  element for each item you want to include in the action bar. For example:

```
res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**Add the Actions to the ActionBar**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Respond to Action Buttons**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this don't work.
How can I implement Up Navigate Button and standart Action Buttons together?

Comment: This isn't in the scope of your question, however you can read through the document that either Rahin or myself posted.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [note](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) in the Android Developer portal.